# How to highlight a point on a Simple Line Chart in NVD3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I have a Simple Line Chart in NVD3 like this one http://nvd3.org/examples/line.html

I would like to highlight (overlapping a circle for example) one particular point (a given x) on my serie.

I haven't found something similar to the Highcharts addPoint() in NVD3, example: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series

Moving the tooltip programmatically could work as well.

Thanks in advance!