# How to highlight only certain coordinates in NVD3 line graph?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, nvd3.js

Can somebody tell me how to highlight  only certain coordinates in a NVD3 line graph depending upon some condition
like if x axis value is above 100,highlight that coordinate.

please see the image at :https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHJaK.jpg

This question or similar question has been asked , but I see no answers.
Thanks in advance.

[How to highlight a point on a Simple Line Chart in NVD3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27096252/how-to-highlight-a-point-on-a-simple-line-chart-in-nvd3)

Comment: The NVD3 API doesn't allow you to do this.

Comment: Thanks Lars for your comment, Can I do it using just D3 or any other javascript lib ?

Comment: Yes, you can select the relevant nodes manually and apply the necessary styling.

Comment: Thanks for quick response , any examples would be appreciated.

Comment: Here's a quick demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rgg7t/25/

Comment: Thank you ! that's what I wanted , ymmd !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The NVD3 API doesn't allow you do to that, so you have to "hack" it and highlight the data points you're interested in yourself. The general approach is to create the circles for the relevant data points by filtering the data:

```
var data = d3.select('#chart svg').datum();
        d3.select('.nv-groups')
            .selectAll("circle.myPoint")
            .data(data.filter(function(d) { return d.y > 3000; }))
            .enter().append("circle").attr("class", "myPoint")
            .attr("cx", function(d) { return chart.xAxis.scale()(d.x); })
            .attr("cy", function(d) { return chart.yAxis.scale()(d.y); })
            .attr("r", 5);
```

Incomplete demo for the first series in the data [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rgg7t/25/).

Comment: I know this answer is incredibly old, trying to get it to do exactly what you did for the first series but for all series which are defined dinamically.

More info on this issue: https://github.com/krispo/angular-nvd3/issues/295#issuecomment-333179615

Any suggestions? Thanks.