# highlight specific point on angular d3 cumulative line

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm using angular nv-d3 and while making a chart, I'd like to have a specific point on the graph be highlighted.

My graph looks like:

[image]

I'm getting the data by consuming a rest response, my graphs will have 1 to 3 lines, and the each line is guaranteed to have the date point that I will be highlighting.

I could also live with just having a straight vertical line through that date, I just want a way to differentiate that specific date in the rest of the chart.

Couldn't find anything in the docs about this, and most of the methods I've found to do this use d3.select and jQuery, but I'm not sure if that will work with angular.

Comment: you already have a vertical line through the date..as shown in the graph.
And d3.select will work with angular there will be no issues.

Comment: ok. do you know if it would be as simple as just finding the node that contains my data point, and appending a colored circle to it? or do I just need to spend more time studying the docs?

Comment: yeas as simple as that ... this is a good answer same as what you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30039550/how-to-highlight-only-certain-coordinates-in-nvd3-line-graph

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think this will require more work though, because I am using the angular-directive d3 library. My code is similar to http://plnkr.co/edit/iIxJT3?p=preview. Hopefully, I can still get to what I need with d3 select.